# Not able to make model start time equal to zero in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am trying to make the time 00:00:00 so I can use my shops opening and closing variables correctly, but I am not able to make the model time 00:00:00.

What I am not able to convert to zero is highlighted in the image below.

[image]

My colleagues are making it 00:00:00 without any hazards, but when I do it, it converts to 12:00:00 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12:00:00am is the same as 00:00:00. It just depends on your system language settings. Don't worry :)

PS: You could have tested this easily using a cyclic event that prints time every minute or so ;)